# fineuploader - initial file list - edit file name functionality

Tags: fine-uploader

When using the inital file list functionality to populate fineuploader with previously stored files, is it possible for the edit filename functionality to be used?

At the moment it seems that the edit elements are hidden in the template, although it would be relatively simply if this functionality were enabled to hook onto the rename trigger and save the updated filename via ajax (what i'm hoping to achieve).

So is there someway to enable the edit filename for the initial file list?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are outside of the scope of a file upload library.  If you want to allow your users to rename a file uploaded in a different session, you will need to provide for this in your custom web application.  You can certainly modify the file list provided by Fine Uploader after it is rendered with the initial files.

Comment: yes i agree, however the initial file list seems to disable the edit file name functionality to begin with. I was wondering if there was a way that i can enable this so that the fineuploader ui offers the renaming interface, with an event like filenameUpdated (i haven't checked the api yet) being triggered on rename which i could hook onto and send the new name to the server.

Comment: The initial file list feature doesn't disable the edit file name feature functionality.  It is only disabled if you don't have the proper elements in your template, or if `autoUpload` is set to `true` (its default value).  "Canned" files (populated as a result of an initial GET request to your server) are not eligible for the edit filename feature, since these files cannot be re-uploaded.  If you'd like to support a workflow where these canned filenames are editable, please open up a feature request.

Comment: I think this will be very useful if you allow editing file name of an initial list and add an endpoint in options to connected to server. Example: namechange: { endpoint: 'url' }. But, no problem for now, I can manage myself.